# How to determine the number of windings needed for a ceiling fan rotor?

Tags: fan

I have picked up from the trash, three oldish ceiling fans. They do not run on electronics. Upon opening the rotor, I can see two coils; one outer and one inner. They look real dirty and I would like to learn to clean them up and replace the coils.

I've seen quite a number of re-coiling projects using stepper motors and Arduinos but I do not understand how to count the number of windings for each coil.

Any ideas where I can start looking on the number of windings for each coil? I saw one diagram which says the outer windings are double that of the inner windings, but I have no reference how many windings is there to begin with.

Comment: Are you replacing the coils because they are damaged? (How have you made sure?)  Or, are you replacing the coils to have a different characteristic?

Comment: Coils in a ceiling fan are probably nearly indestructible.   You'd know if they were bad - They'd be blackened and burnt.  Just clean with a vacuum and maybe a soft brush if it bugs you.   In other words, don't fix what's not broken....

Comment: Hello @Theodore I wanted to make them as brand new as possible.

Comment: @KyleB Sounds like a plan.